# Subscripting syntax for NSMapTable in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, syntax, objective-c-category

I'm using `NSMapTable` in a number of places in an iOS 6 project, and would like to be able to use the new dictionary subscripting style for accessing objects. (`NSMapTable` behaves mostly like an `NSMutableDictionary`, but can be configured with various memory management options for the keys and values it stores. More background in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904533/nsmaptable-and-nsmutabledictionary-differences).)

The compiler reports this when attempting to use subscripting syntax on an `NSMapTable` instance:

> Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSMapTable *'.

How can I use a category to extend `NSMapTable` to allow the new `NSDictionary`-style subscripting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer's actually simple; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658669/how-to-enable-the-new-objective-c-object-literals-on-ios) for more information about how subscripting is implemented. Add a category like this.

Header:

```
@interface NSMapTable (Subscripting)

- (void)setObject:(id)obj forKeyedSubscript:(id <NSCopying>)key;
- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
@implementation NSMapTable (Subscripting)

- (void)setObject:(id)obj forKeyedSubscript:(id <NSCopying>)key {
    [self setObject:obj forKey:key];
}

- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key {
    return [self objectForKey:key];
}

@end
```

This makes me wonder, for a moment, whether subscript access is actually a tiny bit slower than the alternative in some or all cases, but the words "premature optimization" make that thought inconsequential.

Comment: IMO, this is not a good idea. `NSMapTable` doesn't have subscripting for a reason. For example, if you've got a `NSMapTable` using `NSPointerFunctionsStrongMemory`, why would you need to conform to `NSCopying`? This category actually cripples `NSMapTable` to a dictionary-like collection.

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic you can avoid usage of `NSCopying` in the subscription methods declarations.

Comment: One of the advantages of the `NSMapTable` is that it *does not* require the objects to conform to the `NSCopying` protocol. So it makes no sense to add it to the category implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Improved @mjh answer with `NSDictionary`'s behavior on setting object for `nil` key and added Obj-C Generics:

```
@interface NSMapTable<KeyType, ObjectType> (Subscripting)

- (void)setObject:(ObjectType)obj forKeyedSubscript:(KeyType)key;
- (ObjectType)objectForKeyedSubscript:(KeyType)key;

@end

@implementation NSMapTable (Subscripting)

- (void)setObject:(id)obj forKeyedSubscript:(id)key {
    if (object) {
        [self setObject:obj forKey:key];
    } else {
        [self removeObjectForKey:key];
    }
}

- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key {
    return [self objectForKey:key];
}

@end
```